# How to get an element inside a _Layout page from a Partial View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a `_Layout` page that contains the standard elements.

```
  <body id="layoutBody">
   <div class="wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_TopMenu")
    @Html.Partial("_LeftMenu")
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
            <b>Version</b> 1.0
        </div>
    </footer>
   </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap"
  </body>
```

Inside of this layout I have a "Home", "Index" page inside the `@RenderBody` with the following div:

```
<div class="small-box bg-yellow">
   <div class="inner">
      <h4>Phone Directory</h4>
      <h5>New</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="icon">
      <i class="mi mi-contact-phone"></i>
   </div>
   <a id="newUserCollapse" role="button" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      Add New User
      <span class="fa fa-user-plus pull-right"></span>
   </a>
   <div id="new" class="sublinks collapse">
      <iframe src="~/PhoneMasters/Create" id="addUserIframe" align="middle" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height :100%; min-height: 600px; padding-top: 0px"></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is disable the scrollbar in the `_Layout` view when the `newUserCollapse` is on `show.bs.collapse`.
Any way that can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To access a a PartialView element in JQuery, you need to use **Document**:

```
$(document).find("#YourScrollId").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the problem is that I am trying to call this from a partial view to get an element inside of the _Layout page. The solution you provided it will work if it was the other way around.

Comment: @1moreLearner I'm sure that when you use Document, you read **All** the elements of the page, so doesn't matter where are you calling from. Did you try to implement this?

Comment: I guess I figured out what the problem is. If I change the event from $('#newUserCollapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () { to $('#newUserCollapse').click( function () your solution works. I don't understand why since I have a data-toggle="collapse" inside that element. Now, if I leave the click event, the scrollbar stays disabled and that's not what I want. I still want the toggle function to be in place. Weird.

Comment: My question now would be how to make the toggle work back and forth?

Comment: @1moreLearner  You can use this little trick in this [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csbtp8zd/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Javascript code somewhere on the page:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          /* Event to disable scrolling when #newUserCollapse is visible */
          $('#newUserCollapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
             $('html, body').css({ overflow: 'hidden', height: '100%' });
          });

          /* Event to restore scrolling when #newUserCollapse is hidden */
          $('#newUserCollapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
             $('html, body').css({ overflow: 'auto', height: 'auto' });
          });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but same case as I replied to Matheus. This is being called from a Partial View trying to retrieve an element from the _Layout.